# Integral problem about probability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, integration, probability-theory

Let $h(x)=\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)},$ and $f(x)$ is the probability density function of r.v. $X$.

If $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+x^2)h(x)dx<\infty$, do we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xh(x)dx=0$?

Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure whether one could say an indefinite integral is bounded or not, i.e. I suppose there are some borders of integration missing.

Comment: The integration could be regarded as expectation. I should put the borders from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: Note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\gt0$. Furthermore, if $f(x)$ is a probability density function, then $f(x-1)$ is also. If $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x h(x-1)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\gt0$. Thus, it is not true for all probability densities.

Comment: For exponential distribution with pdf $f(x)=e^{-x}$ ($x>0$) we get $h(x)=f(x)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xh(x)dx=1$.